# Android ImageView and Custom Image view

Tags: android, kotlin

Ok, what i am trying to do is this i want to have an image which is music notation treble clef and each note on a scale in music would be programmatically drawn on a notation . So on the first line would be an E note and in between would be an F and so on ... If you know what i mean ...

I have notes and notation as drawables . Notation would be add as background image and note by note would be add at precise point on to notation .

This is my XML:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="245dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="136dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="40sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.example.musictheoryquiz.IntervalView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Yes i created activity and then i am calling from xml my view . The problem is  i am trying to override onDraw method in which i am trying to call notation.png drawable and nothing. I tried with bitmap , i tried

```
 super.onDraw(canvas)
    val draw : Drawable? = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.notation, null)
    if (draw != null) {
        draw.draw(canvas)
    }
```

And couple of other methods to call drawable picture and nothing . I am looking for ideas how to solve this , how to draw this in a view . I was thinking if i could have all the notes in array and every note would have coordinates so when i call any note it would be passed with coordinates where to put it on the picture ...

Thank you :D . If you have any questions ask :) .

Comment: Which class does `IntervalView` extend? My first guess would be that the `<LinearLayout>` and the `<IntervalView>` are shrinking to nothing, because you've got `wrap_content` for all of their dimensions. What happens if you change all of those to `match_parent` on the `<LinearLayout>` and the `<IntervalView>`?

Answer (score 0):

Okey, here is the solution :D . I created 3 methods overlay, resize and makeTransparent.

Overlay:

```
fun overlay(bmp1 : Bitmap, noteOne : Note, noteTwo : Note) : Bitmap {

        val bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.width, bmp1.height, bmp1.config)
        val canvas = Canvas(bmOverlay)


        var resizedNoteOne : Bitmap
        var resizedNoteTwo : Bitmap

        if(noteOne.hasMinus == true && noteTwo.hasMinus == false){
            resizedNoteOne = getResizedBitmap(noteOne.icon_Bitmap, bmOverlay.width / 13.475f, bmOverlay.height / 3.1f)
            resizedNoteTwo = getResizedBitmap(noteTwo.icon_Bitmap, bmOverlay.width / 21.56f, bmOverlay.height / 3.1f)
        }
        else if(noteOne.hasMinus == false && noteTwo.hasMinus == true){
            resizedNoteOne = getResizedBitmap(noteOne.icon_Bitmap, bmOverlay.width / 21.56f, bmOverlay.height / 3.1f)
            resizedNoteTwo = getResizedBitmap(noteTwo.icon_Bitmap, bmOverlay.width / 13.475f, bmOverlay.height / 3.1f)
        }
        else if (noteOne.hasMinus == true && noteTwo.hasMinus == true){
            resizedNoteOne = getResizedBitmap(noteOne.icon_Bitmap, bmOverlay.width / 13.475f, bmOverlay.height / 3.1f)
            resizedNoteTwo = getResizedBitmap(noteTwo.icon_Bitmap, bmOverlay.width / 13.475f, bmOverlay.height / 3.1f)
        }
        else {
            resizedNoteOne = getResizedBitmap(noteOne.icon_Bitmap, bmOverlay.width / 21.56f, bmOverlay.height / 3.1f)
            resizedNoteTwo = getResizedBitmap(noteTwo.icon_Bitmap, bmOverlay.width / 21.56f, bmOverlay.height / 3.1f)
        }


        var bitmapTransparentNoteOne = makeTransparent(resizedNoteOne, Color.WHITE)
        var bitmapTransparentNoteTwo = makeTransparent(resizedNoteTwo, Color.WHITE)




        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, Matrix(), null)

        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapTransparentNoteOne, bmOverlay.width / 5.450f, bmOverlay.height / noteOne.coord_Top_division_value, null)

        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapTransparentNoteTwo, bmOverlay.width / 1.200f, bmOverlay.height / noteTwo.coord_Top_division_value, null)
       // canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapTransparentNoteTwo, bmOverlay.width / 1.200f, bmOverlay.height / , null)


       // canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapTransparentNoteOne, noteOne.coord_Left, noteOne.coord_Top, null)
        //canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapTransparentNoteTwo, noteTwo.coord_Left, noteTwo.coord_Top, null)
        return bmOverlay
    }
```

Resize:

```
fun overlay(bmp1 : Bitmap, noteOne : Note, noteTwo : Note) : Bitmap {

        val bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.width, bmp1.height, bmp1.config)
        val canvas = Canvas(bmOverlay)


        var resizedNoteOne : Bitmap
        var resizedNoteTwo : Bitmap

        if(noteOne.hasMinus == true && noteTwo.hasMinus == false){
            resizedNoteOne = getResizedBitmap(noteOne.icon_Bitmap, bmOverlay.width / 13.475f, bmOverlay.height / 3.1f)
            resizedNoteTwo = getResizedBitmap(noteTwo.icon_Bitmap, bmOverlay.width / 21.56f, bmOverlay.height / 3.1f)
        }
        else if(noteOne.hasMinus == false && noteTwo.hasMinus == true){
            resizedNoteOne = getResizedBitmap(noteOne.icon_Bitmap, bmOverlay.width / 21.56f, bmOverlay.height / 3.1f)
            resizedNoteTwo = getResizedBitmap(noteTwo.icon_Bitmap, bmOverlay.width / 13.475f, bmOverlay.height / 3.1f)
        }
        else if (noteOne.hasMinus == true && noteTwo.hasMinus == true){
            resizedNoteOne = getResizedBitmap(noteOne.icon_Bitmap, bmOverlay.width / 13.475f, bmOverlay.height / 3.1f)
            resizedNoteTwo = getResizedBitmap(noteTwo.icon_Bitmap, bmOverlay.width / 13.475f, bmOverlay.height / 3.1f)
        }
        else {
            resizedNoteOne = getResizedBitmap(noteOne.icon_Bitmap, bmOverlay.width / 21.56f, bmOverlay.height / 3.1f)
            resizedNoteTwo = getResizedBitmap(noteTwo.icon_Bitmap, bmOverlay.width / 21.56f, bmOverlay.height / 3.1f)
        }


        var bitmapTransparentNoteOne = makeTransparent(resizedNoteOne, Color.WHITE)
        var bitmapTransparentNoteTwo = makeTransparent(resizedNoteTwo, Color.WHITE)




        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, Matrix(), null)

        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapTransparentNoteOne, bmOverlay.width / 5.450f, bmOverlay.height / noteOne.coord_Top_division_value, null)

        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapTransparentNoteTwo, bmOverlay.width / 1.200f, bmOverlay.height / noteTwo.coord_Top_division_value, null)
       // canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapTransparentNoteTwo, bmOverlay.width / 1.200f, bmOverlay.height / , null)


       // canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapTransparentNoteOne, noteOne.coord_Left, noteOne.coord_Top, null)
        //canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapTransparentNoteTwo, noteTwo.coord_Left, noteTwo.coord_Top, null)
        return bmOverlay
    }
```

makeTransparent:

```
fun makeTransparent(bitmap : Bitmap, transparentColor : Int ) : Bitmap {
        var width : Int = bitmap.width
        var height : Int = bitmap.height
        var changedBitmap : Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        var arrayLenght = changedBitmap.height * changedBitmap.width
        var allpixels = IntArray(arrayLenght)
        bitmap.getPixels(allpixels, 0, width, 0,0, width, height)

        for (i in 0 until arrayLenght) {
            if (allpixels[i] == transparentColor)
                allpixels[i] = Color.alpha(Color.TRANSPARENT)
        }

        changedBitmap.setPixels(allpixels, 0, changedBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, changedBitmap.getWidth(), changedBitmap.getHeight());

        return changedBitmap

    }
```

And all this could be done just by using matrix and couple of lines of code like this:

```
matrix.reset()
matrix.setScale(0.2f, 0.2f)
matrix.postTranslate("some coordinates, where you want to put it on the screen")
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapTransparentNoteOne, matrix, null)
```

And that is it .